# Android WebView AJAX sandbox

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, webview, sandbox

I need to embed WebView in my application, which has to pull some data via AJAX from multiple remote servers. Unfortunetely due to ajax sandbox, connections to foreign servers are blocked. How can I disable it, as the js code I'm running is trusted?

There's a simple workaround to allow connections to single server. It's as simple as using loadDataWithBaseUrl and passing the top level url as the first parameter. But what to do, when js should be able to access multiple different domains?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are the pages loaded into the webview local? i.e, Are they loaded from the local file system like: `file://yourpage.html` or are they remote pages?

Webpages loaded locally are not affected by the cross-domain ajax restrictions so you can load whatever you like.

If they're remote pages then i'm not sure how you're going to get around it, perhaps setup your own webservice on the same domain as where the pages are served from which simply fetches the data from the remote services and spits it back